# Best verb for situation below

Tags: verbs

For example When I buy something from my supplier  he allow me to make payment after 30 days .In this case which verb should I use in sentence below?

> My supplier provides a payment term of 30 days for me.
>
> My supplier enables a payment term of 30 days for me.
>
> My supplier procures a payment term of 30 days for me

Answer (score 1):

Are you the only person for whom this supplier allows 30 days for payment? If not, and this is their standard business practice, it isn't really "for you", and they don't really *do* anything special, so no verb is required. You could just say:

> My supplier *has* a payment term of 30 days.

If this *is* a special arrangement for you, then I would suggest:

> My supplier *gives me* a payment term of 30 days.

or perhaps:

> My supplier *allows me 30 days* for payment.

Comment: He allow only me , for other customer he requires cash payment.

Comment: @Foreignstudent that's nice of him. I've covered both possibilities.